# Strange constructor behavior

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and this is what I'm trying to figure out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int x = 1;
    bool y = true;

    A(int _x, bool _y) : x(_x), y(_y)
    {
        cout << "Constructor #1" << endl;
    }

    A(std::initializer_list<int> init_list)
    {
        cout << "Constructor #2" << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A Aobj1(10, false);
    A Aobj2(20, "false");
    A Aobj3{30, false};
    A Aobj4{40, "false"};

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> ```
> Constructor #1
> Constructor #1
> Constructor #2
> Constructor #1
> ```

- The first call to constructor #1 is fine
- Now the second construction of `Aobj2(int, string)` calling constructor #1 is strange. How is the compiler calling the `(int, bool)` constructor with a string argument? The "false" `bool` is not even converted to an int.
- `Aobj3` is also OK. Although the `initializer_list` is of type int, the compiler calls this because of brace-initialization and converts the bool to an int.
- This one again baffles me. I would have expected this to be an error because a string cannot be converted to an int (as it was with the bool), and also expected the compiler to be calling the `initializer_list` constructor because it is a braced initialization. But the compiler chooses the (int, bool) constructor.

What is some background on the logic of the compiler?

Comment: "I am using VS2013" - Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"false"` is a `const char[6]` which decays to `const char*` and pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`. That's why the compiler can call your constructor taking a `int` and a `bool`, since the compiler is allowed to perform *one* implicit conversion to make a function argument match.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info on "compiler is allowed to make one implicit conversion". I was wondering why the bool is not then converted to an int and called constructor #4.

Comment: "false" is a **not** `const char*`. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @taskinoor `"false"` is a `const char[6]` which decays to a `const char*`...? This is a real tricky issue I once stumbled myself about. In my case, the alternative was `A::A(int, std::string)` and I was really suprised when I realized that `A::A(int, bool)` was preferred. It does make sense but hit me unexpectedly.

Comment: @Scheff Interesting case. Converting `const char*` to `std::string` requires user-defined conversion (via the constructor of `std::string`); converting `const char*` to `bool` is standard conversion. Then the latter is perferred.

Comment: @taskinoor I fixed that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl now it looks better. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @madu Note that you can use [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) to say that a certain constructor is *not* allowed to be used by the compiler for implicit conversions. That's often useful to prevent unwanted implicit conversions.

Answer (score 8):

> Now the second construction of `Aobj2(int, string)` calling constructor #1 is strange. How is the compiler calling the `(int, bool)` constructor with a string argument?

More precisely, `"false"` is of type `const char[6]` and could [decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) to `const char*`, i.e. a pointer, and then could [implicitly convert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions) to `bool`.

> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become `false`. All other values become `true`.

For the 4th case, the parameter `std::initializer_list<int>` can't match the argument `40, "false"`, because there're no implicit conversion converting pointer to `int`. Then the constructor taking `int, bool` is selected, because `"false"` could be converted to `bool` implicitly as the above explained.

Comment: a pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool` but not to `int`?? (*More precisely, "false" is of type const char[6] and could decay to `const char*`, i.e. a pointer, and then could implicitly convert to `boo`l.*  **vs.** *because there're no implicit conversion converting pointer to `int`*)

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yes. A pointer could implicitly convert to `bool` but not to `int`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/QDgcZJf2gzF4w02h

Comment: I find it very hard to understand... I see pointers as a numeric value corresponding to an address, which I can implictly change to a numeric value corrsponding to anything else (i.e. `int`). `bool` is just a very limited `int` that can't reach the values a pointer / `int` can, so the convertion should work the other way around, as I see it. Can you please explain?

Comment: @CIsForCookies Maybe you're confusing with *implicit conversion* and *explicit conversion*? Implicit conversion from pointer to `bool` is allowed, but converting pointer to `int` requires explicit conversion, .e.g. [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). It means you could do it but you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Not confusing, just not understanding... I'm under the impression that implicit conversion comes when the conversion is somewhat obvious, and I say, pointer is much more like `int` then like `bool` so I would expect the conversion to work the other way around

Comment: @CIsForCookies I get what you meant, but it's not easy to explain.. Converting pointer to `bool` seems straightforward to me, behavior is simple and clear; the converted result depends on whether the pointer is null pointer or not, and then it could be used to represent the pointer is a null pointer or not. Converting to an `int` is not obvious as to `bool`; in concept the pointer is just an object pointing to sth, then what's the purpose to convert it to `int`? We can't use the converted result for arithmetic operation. It might be the memory address, but it's not the general use case of int.